# Convert BouncyCastle DSAPrivateKeyParameters to System.Security.Cryptography.DSAParameters

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate, bouncycastle, dsa

I am trying to generate a new self-signed X509 certificate (instance of `X509Certificate2`) *with private key* using Bouncy Castle. I googled some examples for RSA and I created this code based on these examples. I use Bouncy Castle for certificate generation and then I am trying to convert it to `X509Certificate2`, but I do not know how to convert Bouncy Castle DSA private key (`DSAPrivateKeyParameters`) to `System.Security.Cryptography.DSAParameters`

```
var keypairgen = new DsaKeyPairGenerator();
DsaParametersGenerator paramgen = new DsaParametersGenerator();

paramgen.Init(1024, 100, new SecureRandom());
DsaKeyGenerationParameters param = new DsaKeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), paramgen.GenerateParameters());

keypairgen.Init(param);
var keypair = keypairgen.GenerateKeyPair();
var gen = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();

var CN = new X509Name("CN=" + "TEST");
var SN = BigInteger.ProbablePrime(120, new Random());

gen.SetSerialNumber(SN);
gen.SetSubjectDN(CN);
gen.SetIssuerDN(CN);
gen.SetNotAfter(DateTime.MaxValue);
gen.SetNotBefore(DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0)));
gen.SetSignatureAlgorithm("sha1WithDSA");
gen.SetPublicKey(keypair.Public);

var newCert = gen.Generate(keypair.Private);

certificateDSA = new X509Certificate2(DotNetUtilities.ToX509Certificate((Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate)newCert));

certificateDSA.PrivateKey = ToDotNetKey(keypair.Private); //!!!! this line !!!!
```

The problematic line is the last one. How should I implement this `ToDotNetKey()`? I thought it would be some easy mapping of properties, but it was not. In `DSAParameters` there is this property called `J` (or `Y`), which is not among Bouncy Castle parameters, for example, so I do not know what value I should put inside.

Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it by myself as a side result of another question. starting from the different direction: I generate the key pair in .NET and then I convert it using DotNetUtilities to Bouncy Castle.

The final working code is here, I hope it will help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32518689/3899583